# Multipart form on mobile devices: control actions that show up after clicking on file input

Tags: html, forms, mobile, multipartform-data

I have a multipart form where I expect users to upload images to my website.

```
<form method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" action="/uploads" id="forminho">
    <div className="btn btn-success" id="submitFileBtn"> 
        Selecionar Imagem
        <input className="form-control2" type="file" name="upload" id="inputFile" onChange={this.submit}/>
    </div>
</form>
```

It works as expected on desktop, but on mobile devices I get a list of apps to choose from that have little or nothing to do with photos. I get: Camera, Camcorder, Voice Recorder and Documents (and there's no option to choose another action).

How can I make it explicit that I'm expecting an image and make this list of actions customized to that?

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5, you can check that uploads are an image with an `accept="image/*"` criterion on the `<input>` as such:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

This should automatically prevent mobiles from allowing you to choose random apps.

Remember to check the upload in the back-end as well! :)